# How to change default download location of chrome browser using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am new to automation and currently using Robot framework. I am trying to change the download location of the browser when running the tests. I tried below code and doesn't work

```
${kwargs}   Create Dictionary  download.default_directory=C:\\
create webdriver  ${G_BROWSER}    ${kwargs}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a pdf file automatically in chrome browser using Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156753/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-automatically-in-chrome-browser-using-robot-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Use the updated suggestion for changing the download directory in the selenium library of Robot Framework.

Instead of using Create WebDriver - the Robot Framework team suggested using Open Browser Keyword to change the download directory

```
 ${prefs} =    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=C:\\Balaji
   Open Browser    https://www.google.com/    chrome    
   options=add_experimental_option("prefs",${prefs})
   Maximize Browser Window
   Set Browser Implicit Wait    20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code
${DownloadFile}=    Get File    ${DownloadPath}

You can give download path(${DownloadPath}) as your wish, automatically, file will be save in that path

Answer (score 0):

```
${path}=    Set Variable    ${downloadPath}
Create Directory    ${path}
${CHROME_OPTIONS}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${prefs}    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${path}
Call Method    ${CHROME_OPTIONS}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${CHROME_OPTIONS}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, could you please elaborate a bit on it and try to explain it if possible ?