# In robot tests , how to check file is downloaded successfully

Tags: robotframework

I am new to robot framework .  My automation test has a step to download a file from web .
How can I check the file is downloaded successfully to my local?
I am using chrome and firefox browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check file by using OperatingSystem library. For exaple you can use keyword like:

```
Wait Until Created
```

or

```
File Should Exist
```

There are more keywords you can find useful, check the docs:

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html

Comment: I have added code to create new directory. I want the file to get downloaded to that new created directory. Currently it gets downloaded to my Downloads folder.How can I ask Robot framework to save the new file to new created folder and not to default download folder

Comment: @Workemail For Firefox check answers in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625311/change-download-directory-using-robot-framework) and for Chrome check answers in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156753/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-automatically-in-chrome-browser-using-robot-framework). Please, consider accepting answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did following and it worked fine for me:
After Clicking on download , I created a directory in my robot framework and specified that path for storing the downloaded file and later verified in that path that file is present